# Cannot trace in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Just recently, I've been trying to learn Actionscript 3 for Adobe Flash.
Unfortunately, I cannot even get the most basic code to work. For some reason, when I run it, noting shows up in output, even though I have it set to trace the word "Hello". My Actionscript file IS seperate from my flash file.

My code is as follows. If you can help me identify the problem, I will be much thankful.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Test extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            trace("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you set the fla's document class file as your Test{} class? If not, go to your publish settings, click on the "flash" tab, settings button beside 'script', and fill in the document class at the top with your class name

Comment: Also don't forget to instantiate at least one instance from that class : `var instance:Test = new Test();` or if it's for a MovieClip in your library, you can also just drag and drop an instance to your stage ...

Comment: @bradley - to clarify, you only need to create a new instance of it if it's not your document class - that gets created once automatically when you run your app

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the debug player. Right-click on your SWF when it shows up - if you don't see an entry for "Debugger", then you're not running the debug player. You can download it from here: https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html (run it once so it becomes the default)